# Integrating App Indexing with Async server calls

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-app-indexing

I'm working on integrating Google app indexing into my android app that will take the URL, query the server for the internal ID of the article, then open that article. I'm a little confused on how to accomplish this though as I don't have as much experience with network calls.

```
  private void openAppIndexedArticle(String data) {
    HomeActivity home = getActivity();
    MyFragment currentFragment = home.getCurrentFragment();
    MyHandler handler = MyHandler.getInstance(mActivity.get());
    String articleUrn = handler.getArticleUrnFromUrl(data);
    ReadingFragment readingFragment = ReadingFragment.createInstance(articleUrn);
    home.openFragment(readingFragment);
  }
```

Here is where I need to fetch the ID in `MyHandler`

```
public String getArticleUrnFromUrl(String url) {
  HttpResponse response = performGET(storyUrl);
  if (response != null) {
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
      GzipResponse gzip = new GzipResponse(response);
      InputStream is = gzip.getContent();
      try {
        String json = IOUtils.toString(is);
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);
        String id = object.optString("articleId");
        gzip.close();
        return new Urn(id, LiEntityType.ARTICLE).toString();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Now when I try this, it gives me a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` which is understandable since it is on the main thread. Whenever I look up AsyncTasks for accomplishing this, I don't understand how they get the data back since the only thing the app is supposed to do right now is open that article - it needs to wait for the request to finish anyway, right? Is this an error I should suppress and just put up a loading screen until it finishes? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you even read AsyncTask documentation ?

Comment: AsyncTask.get() seems to accomplish what I wanted but I just felt it defeated the purpose of running something in the background if you're waiting for it anyway. I was just hoping for some explanation on best practices for this sort of issue instead of something like populating a list or object that doesn't require all the data right away.

Comment: call the asynctask then do whatever you need to in the onPostExecute, there is no other way